# Limbo Achievements

Tags: achievements, limbo

I'm just about at the end of Limbo, and I still haven't gotten any achievements.  How do you get the achievements in Limbo?

Answer (score 10):

[Here](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/limbo/achievements/)'s the list, if you click each one it tells you how to get them.

> There are 12 achievements with a total of 200 points.
>
> - [Wrong Way](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/limbo/achievement/40930-Wrong-Way.html): That's not right
> - [Altitude is attitude](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/limbo/achievement/40931-Altitude-is-attitude.html): Exploration off the ground
> - [It's Stuck](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/limbo/achievement/40932-It-s-Stuck.html): Prepare a dry landing
> - [Urban Exploration](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/limbo/achievement/40933-Urban-Exploration.html): Involves heavy lifting
> - [Alone in the Dark](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/limbo/achievement/40934-Alone-in-the-Dark.html): Beneath the arthropod
> - [Climbing the Cog](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/limbo/achievement/40935-Climbing-the-Cog.html): Don't pull the lever just because you can
> - [Backtracking](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/limbo/achievement/40936-Backtracking.html): Ride the crates
> - [Guided by Sparks](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/limbo/achievement/40937-Guided-by-Sparks.html): The crate is key
> - [Under Ground](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/limbo/achievement/40938-Under-Ground.html): Vertical passageway
> - [Going Up](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/limbo/achievement/40939-Going-Up.html): Don't let gravity keep you down
> - [Where Credit is due](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/limbo/achievement/40940-Where-Credit-is-due.html): Persistence has its own reward
> - [No Point in Dying](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/limbo/achievement/40941-No-Point-in-Dying.html): Complete the game in one sitting with five or less deaths

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I'm just not very good at Limbo.

Comment: Don't feel down, @Jake. Most of the achievements relate to finding glowing blobs, which are always remarkably well hidden. I'd say that few people will find many without guides, videos, etc.